# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{2x+1}$

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 - 4}}{2x+1}$.

I need help solving this limit. I've tried to use the conjugate and factor under the square root but it does not cancel.

Comment: It might be easier to express the numerator in terms of rational powers. So you could rewrite as $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\cfrac{(x^4-4)^{\frac12}}{2x+1}$ then simplify a little further and then evaluate. You’ll have an easier time visualizing the behavior of the limit

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Divide the top and bottom by $x$ to get: $\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2x+1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\tfrac{4}{x^2}}}{2+\tfrac{1}{x}}$.

Now, it should be easy to take the limit as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For such problems divide all the terms with $x$ having the highest power. Then as $x$ approaches $\infty$ then $\frac{1}{\infty}$ approaches $0$ thus here we divide numerator and denominator by $x$ and in numerator it goes under root and becomes $x^2$ so our limit becomes $\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}}{2+\frac{1}{x}}$ this pugging in $\infty$ we get $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ thus the limit is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace $x=\frac{1}{y}$ Which will imply that $$\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{y})^2-4}}{2(\frac{1}{y})+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

take x common from both numerator and denominator and cancel out.Next, put x=infinity.that term will be 0.